# Kafka Consumer which writes into multiple file

Tags: file-io, apache-kafka

I have to implement a kafka consumer which reads data from a topic and writes it a file based on the account id(will be close to million) present in the payload. Assuming there will be around 3K events per second. Is it ok to open and close file for each message read? 
or should I consider a different approach?

Comment: Is it going to be a single file? or each account id will have its own unique file?

Comment: Each accountid will have it own unique file.

Comment: Ok.. The answer should work for you then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming following:

1. Each account id will be unique and will have its own unique file.
2. It is okay to have a little lag in the data in the file, i.e. the data in the file will be near real time.
3. The data read per event is not huge.

Solution:

1. Kafka Consumer reads the data and writes to a database, preferably a NoSQL db.
2. A separate Single thread periodically reads the database for new records inserted, groups them by accountId.
3. Then iterates over the accoundId and for each accountId opens the File, writes the data at once, closes the File and moves to the next accountId.

Advantages:

1. Your consumer will not be blocked due to File Handling, as the two operations are decoupled.
2. Even if File Handling fails then the data is always present in DB to reprocess.

Comment: this is something to the alternate solution I had in mind as this data is already being persisted to cassandra. Wanted to explore an option where I can avoid spikes in cassandra during this operation. The main goal is to create daily files for each account.

Comment: If the data is already in Cassandra then why not read it from there. Read operation is not really a spike.

Answer (score 0):

If your account id repeats, then it is better to windowing. You can aggregate all events of say 1 min by windowing, then you can group events by key and process all accountId at once.

This way, you will not have to open a file multiple times.

Comment: There is no guarantee that I'll see all account ids multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It is not okay to open a file for every single message, you should buffer a fixed amount of message, then write to a file when you each that limit.

---

You can use the HDFS Kafka Connector provided by Confluent to manage this.

If configured with the `FieldPartitioner` writing out to a local filesystem given `store.url=file:///tmp`, for example, that will create one directory per unique accountId field in your topic. Then the `flush.size` configuration determines how many messages will end up in a single file

Hadoop does not need to be installed as the HDFS libraries are included in the Kafka Connect classpath and they support local filesystems

You would start it like this after creating two property files

```
bin/connect-standalone worker.properties hdfs-local-connect.properties
```

Comment: I don't think this will work out for me. I have some logic which checks if the data is to be written to file or not. Forgot to mentions this each account id will have its own directory and file names would be based on the day.